# Issue with placing a div in the right area

Tags: html, css, layout

http://codepen.io/MarcMurray/pen/GBwEt

I'm curently laying out a page for an assignment, and am having bit of a brain fart in regard to positioning the content container beside the side bar and below the header.
I know it should be a simple fix, but when i change the margins it pushes the whole page down.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left` to `.cardinfo` CSS class